# What is this symbol on the ground connection?

Tags: ground, symbol

I've come across the following symbol, boxed in red, in a single line diagram for a switchboard. From looking at it, I'm interpreting it as some sort of ground connector, but I want to confirm.

[image: Symbol in question]

I have tried my best to search for it online but I've had no luck. I have tried the following and combinations of the following: `ground connection` `ground symbols` `ground bus connection` `ground link` `ground disconnect` `electrical bus connection symbol`

What is this symbol?

Comment: Try “grid arc suppression with 500 MCM cable. 3/0 size”

Comment: I wasn't able to find that symbol using any of those keywords. Found myself a few other new symbols though.

Comment: OK I guess it is a non-std symbol. But definitely not a 3phase & Neutral short circuit to Ground Bus.   but no kV is given.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Found it. I stumbled across the symbol in the first diagram while searching up `TVSS schematics`. I then decided to go really general with the search and found the second diagram using `service entrance rated switchboard schematic`.

It is a disconnect link or bonding jumper.

---

**Diagram 1**

[image: TVSS Schematic]

[Source for Diagram 1](http://www.nooutage.com/images/asco300se-diagram.gif) on [this web page](http://www.nooutage.com/asco300s.htm).

---

**Diagram 2**

[image: Switchboard Schematic]

[Source for Diagram 2](https://www.toboaenergy.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/10/600-3000ASCO.jpg) on [this web page](https://www.toboaenergy.com/product/600-amp-asco-300-service-entrance-rated-automatic-transfer-switch-3-phase-3-pole/).

Answer (score 1):

from the context(circuit breaker switch), it looks like a thermal overload device symbol:

https://gallery.proficad.eu/Symbols/electrical-installations/switchgear-and-protective-devices-(ANSI)/protective-devices/circuit-breakers/circuit-breaker-with-thermal-overload-device-(form-1)-.html

Also matches the wiki-provided symbol for "thermal fuse."

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thermal_cutoff

Comment: Does it make sense to have a thermal overload on the ground connection? Say there is a major fault to ground in the switchboard, what would happen if that line was disconnected?

Comment: Jeff - Thanks for trying to help, but IMHO the symbols in the links you provide look *different* to the one highlighted in red in the original question, and therefore are not the answer to the question. :-(